# How do I type parseLiteral parameter in date scalar?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, nestjs

How do I type `ast`?

```
import { CustomScalar, Scalar } from '@nestjs/graphql'
import { Kind } from 'graphql'
export class DateScalar implements CustomScalar<number, Date> {
  description = 'Date custom scalar type'

  parseValue(value: number): Date {
    return new Date(value) // value from the client
  }

  serialize(value: Date): number {
    return value.getTime() // value sent to the client
  }

  parseLiteral(ast): Date { // <-- ???
    if (ast.kind === Kind.INT) {
      return new Date(ast.value)
    }
    return null
  }
}
```

I tried to use

```
interface AST {
  kind: string
  value: number
}
```

but then I do get the error

```
  Property 'parseLiteral' in type 'DateScalar' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CustomScalar<number, Date>'.
    Type '(ast: AST) => Date' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLScalarLiteralParser<Date>'.
      Types of parameters 'ast' and 'valueNode' are incompatible.
        Type 'ValueNode' is not assignable to type 'AST'.
          Property 'value' is missing in type 'VariableNode' but required in type 'AST'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, by [looking at Nest's `custom-scalar` interface](https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/blob/master/lib/interfaces/custom-scalar.interface.ts#L11) we can see that `parseLiteral` is of type `GraphQLScalarLiteralParser<K>` from `graphql`. [After digging around GraphQL-js's types](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/type/definition.d.ts#L341) I found this definition where `ast` is also called a `ValueNode`. [A `ValueNode` is a union of other value nodes](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/language/ast.d.ts#L310) that contains things like `NullValueNode` and `ObjectValueNode` which don't have `value` as properties, hence why you're getting that error.

All of that preface and linking to say: if you want to type it, use `import { ValueNode } from 'graphql';` and use the type `ValueNode`. By using `ast.Kind === Kind.INT` the `ast` will get casted to an `IntValueNode` which has the field `value` as a property. Should clear up any type issues you've got